# Highcharts - Display legend for Pie chart in two columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend, pie-chart

I have been using Highcharts(v2.1.9) to generate some pie charts. The charts are generated quite well, however I am having some problems with displaying the legend.

The legend shows in vertical view, but instead of all the legend items showing, some are hidden. I believe this is due to the navigation option being automatically enabled, which pages all of the other legend items that do not fit within the container.

Instead of paging the rest of the legend items, I want to show them in a second column, side by side with the first column.

This data is dynamic so the number of legend items/pie sectors may change over time. The solution must be able to handle more than two columns if the sectors increase.

I think one way to turn off the navigation option is to use the `useHTML: true` option but I haven't been able to style it in the way that I want.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fb3x9ys/

```
$(function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Build the chart
        $('#container').highcharts({

                        chart: {
                                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                                plotBorderWidth: null,
                                plotShadow: false,
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                width: 800,
                                height: 280
                            },
                            credits: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            legend: {
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                labelFormatter: function() {
                                    var total = 0, percentage; 


                                        $.each(this.series.data, function() { 
                                        total+=this.y; 
                                        }); 
                                        percentage=((this.y/total)*100).toFixed(2); 
                                        return '<span style="color:#000000,font-size:12px !important;"><b>'+ this.name + '</b></span><br/><span style="color:#000000,font-size:12px !important;">'+percentage+'%</span>'; 
                                },                 
                                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                                x:185,
                                y:0,
                                layout: 'vertical',
                                width: 600,
                                height:280,
                                itemWidth: 600,
                                symbolWidth: 7,
                                symbolHeight: 28

                            },
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                pie: {
                                    allowPointSelect: true,
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    size: 275,
                                    center: ["16%", "50%"],
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: false,
                                    },
                                    showInLegend: true,
                                    minSize: 130,
                                    colors: [
                                    '#7DA0B0',
                                    '#9264AA',
                                    '#4F2A72',
                                    '#9A3968',
                                    '#BF5269',
                                    '#E16553',
                                    '#E3985E',
                                    '#E4BF80',
                                    '#75C494',
                                    '#52584B'
                                ]
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                type: 'pie',
                                name: 'Sector',
                                data:{"data":[["ENERGY",17.4],["FINANCIALS",15.1],["CONSUMER STAPLES",14.9],["UTILITIES",14.88],["MATERIALS",7.59],["REAL ESTATE",7.24],["TELECOMMUNICATION SERVICES",7.08],["CONSUMER DISCRETIONARY",6.95],["INDUSTRIALS",5.28],["HEALTH CARE",2.64],["CASH",0.95]]}.data
                            }]


        });
    });

});
```

I want to thank all responses in advance. I have been stuck on this for a few days now and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should consider disabling default legend, and instead create your own, just like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am actually rendering the chart on the server side by inputting my own JavaScript file into the highcharts-convert.js running with PhantomJS. Is it possible to still create divs and style them using CSS?

Comment: Nope, it's not possible. Exporting server works only for SVG. You can try to work with height/maxHeight and different layout.

Comment: Thanks but I got it using the horizontal layout and then using the useHTML option. Its not exactly the solution that I wanted but it's good enough.

Comment: That's what I mean by saying "different layout" ;) Anyway, be aware that useHTML options doesn't work for exporting..

Comment: Oh really? When I put the useHTML option, the paging went away and all the items showed up. Anyways it's all good now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeap, really, see [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) -> `The downsides are that it will always be laid out on top of all other SVG content, and that it is not rendered the same way in exported charts.` ;)

Comment: I'm facing the exact same and i tried all the soln mentioned in the comment thread, i was able to get the legends into 2 cols, but i still see the pagination below even when I useHTML option set to true/false. I tried setting height, but didnt work. Can I do something like itemHeight to make the pagination go away?

Comment: @ATD: can you post your working code in the fiddle, I updated your fiddle with the solution you mentioned work for you and I dont quite see it working, just want to test since im facing very similar issue.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try laying out the legends horizontally and setting `itemWidth` to something greater than 80. That worked for me.

*Example*:

```
legend: {
    itemWidth: 80
}
```